# Authorize an angular.js app to access a Web API 2 project secured by Azure Active Directory auth

Tags: angularjs, azure, azure-active-directory, adal, adal.js

Using the Microsoft stack (via Visual Studio 2015) I'm building a solution that has what appears to be a somewhat unique structure.

The solution has two important projects, one is a Web API 2 project, and the other is purely a web client, an angular.js app where the only file served up by the IIS server is the index.html file. On publish, both will be hosted at different domain names because we want multiple types of clients (web, mobile, native) to be able to access the web api.

If I want to secure my Web API project using Azure Active Directory application authentication (wow that's an awesome name), how can I authorize the angular.js web application, which is hosted at a different domain name than the web api to call to successfully call the web api?

Right now I'm exploring adal.js on the web client and Owin on the web api and can't get calls from the front-end to be allowed through to the web api.

Thanks!

Comment: I think you would essentially hit a web api to login the user, which would return a token that you would pass to subsequent API called in the header. I have done this many times with .NET apis.

Comment: Complete walkthrough here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-devquickstarts-angular/

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable CORS for your web api so that clients from different domain can access the API. More details instructions are here: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-angularjs-singlepageapp-dotnet-webapi